# Why is the movie called "Dirty Dancing"?

Tags: title, dirty-dancing

I saw this movie, the dance moves look like salsa and appear romantic.

In that case, why is the movie called *"Dirty Dancing"*?

Comment: Keep in mind, this is the same era where they would only show "Elvis the Pelvis" from the waist up [because of his "lewd" hip gyrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley#1956.E2.80.931958:_Commercial_breakout_and_controversy). (See the section on the "Milton Berle Show".)

Comment: Why is *any* movie called "Dirty Dancing"?

Comment: (1) Alliteration, and (2) nobody would watch a movie called "romantic dancing".

Comment: @user1118321  "this is the same era" -- same era? Dirty Dancing was 20+ years AFTER Elvis was accepted as an entertainer for the whole family.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a lot of those dance moves would cause trouble at most public school dances in the US. They are clearly provocative - like physical sexual innuendo. The idea of what is "romantic" and what is "dirty" might be cultural.

Comment: @Hejazzman I think User1118321 means the era in which the movie is set, not when it was released.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because it's not white, formal dancing. Especially in 1950s/1960s upper class culture. That type of dancing is structured, stiff. The dancers have space between them, very proper like. "Dirty Dancing" on the other hand, leaves no space for Jesus. It's basically the 1960s version of having sex on the dance floor.

First, the movie was based on the writer's personal life:

> Dirty Dancing is based in large part on screenwriter Eleanor Bergstein's own childhood: she is the younger daughter of a Jewish doctor from New York, spent summers with her family in the Catskills, participated in "Dirty Dancing" competitions, and was herself nicknamed "Baby" as a girl. In 1980, Bergstein wrote a screenplay for the Michael Douglas film, *It's My Turn*. However, the producers cut an erotic dancing scene from the script, much to her dismay. She then conceived a new story, focused almost exclusively on dancing. In 1984, she pitched the idea to MGM executive Eileen Miselle, who liked it and teamed Bergstein with producer Linda Gottlieb. They set the film in 1963, with the character of Baby based on Bergstein's own life.

Second, her personal life involved Mambo, not Salsa, though most of film is a mix of both and others.

Comment: I disagree with your description of "white, formal dancing" as with one where there's a space between dancers. At least one dance doesn't fit this description: waltz. For instance, Viennese waltz dancers are pretty much joined by the cores when dancing properly, their hips are between each other, it's very close contact. Then you have tango, especially Argentine tango. Salsa normally leaves more space between dancers than tango and waltz, though there's more touching by hands of the female by male. That's probably what makes it look "dirtier". Also, it's "mambo" not "mamba"

Comment: @Aksakal the waltz was seen as extremely scandalous when it first made its way into Anglophone culture ("No event ever produced so great a sensation in English society as the introduction of the waltz in 1813." – Thomas Raikes). After 150 years it had been acclimatised to.

Comment: @aksakal tango evolved from lower class African slaves in Argentina and would have given the upper class white people heart attacks at that time. Much like the plot of this movie. You consider Argentina white, as in Anglo saxen European? And are you sure? I thought the writer spent her youth training attack snakes.

Comment: @cde, I'm pretty sure about mambo dance vs mamba snakes. Both tango and waltz were socially acceptable in 1960s when the movie's set. Also, I wouldn't call "white" dancing stiff. It may appear so when the dancers are dummies, but none of the "white" dances feel stiff to me. And what is exactly "white" dance? Polka? It's not stiff either. I think you're right pointing out to the nature of the dancing in the movie as a reason for "dirty" qualifier, I only disagree with characterization of 
"clean" dances in your post. They're still elegant and sensual, but in a more subtle ways than mambo/salsa

Comment: Sorry, this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRTVoN95miM ) is pretty much the definition of stiff. And white.

Comment: "leaves no space for Jesus" - LMFAO

Comment: @Aksakal Also, early versions of the Waltz look very little like what we know as the waltz today.

Comment: @Yorik, that's not fair. Your link's to beginners. Look at the pros: https://youtu.be/JrwmbcI9yPE?t=1m3s I don't think this looks stiff at all. Look at the distance between dancers, and how their legs are placed vs the video you linked to. There's a lot of close contact, and the ladies look and move super attractively. They don't gyrate their hips like in mambo, but the contact to the lead is tight all the time in viennese waltz

Comment: @Aksakal This is how top competitors danced waltz in 1950's: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hTSSv5sqVo

Answer (score 13):

The "Dirty Dancing" takes place in the partying that the resort staff take part in after their work days end.

Public dancing at the time the movie was set (1963) was a more sedate affair and the gyrations and sexy moves involved in the parties would have "shocked" the suburban parents of the time.

Hence, this type of dancing would have been considered sinful, or *dirty*.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Dancing)

> The staff hold secret after-hours parties in their quarters, and Baby is surprised by the "dirty dancing" they engage in. Intrigued, Baby receives a brief, impromptu dance lesson from Johnny.